# Ajax javascript Map to Spring controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring

I am trying ajax Javascript `Map`, to spring controller. but it's getting null in backend. Please excuse if i am repeating question.

1. I can't change `Map` type, as my whole front end logic on it. Because `set`, `get` and `has` method from `Map` is what I need.

```
var ansMap = new Map(); // This way i created object

// added many values in ansMap,

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        contentType : 'application/json',
        //cache: false,
        dataType : 'json',
        data : ansMap, // can't JSON.stringy(ansMap) as it gives empty json
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
```

Spring code

```
@RequestMapping (value="myUrl", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String saveData(@RequestParam(required = false, value = "mapData") Map<String,List<String>> mapData, Model map)
    {
        log.info("Call Success");
        log.info("mapData: "+mapData);
```

Please suggest what needs to be done here.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually send your Map without mutating the value

```
var ansMap = new Map(); // This way i created object

// added many values in ansMap,

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        contentType : 'application/json',
        //cache: false,
        dataType : 'json',
        data : JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(ansMap)), // can't JSON.stringy(ansMap) as it gives empty json
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
```

That will turn it into a javascript object.

Object.fromEntries Will turn you Map into a javascript object, without altering the original `Map`

Regarding your backend i think you mis-interpret the @RequestParam annotation
The @RequestParam is to extract **query** parameters, form parameters and even files from the request.

I think that what you are looking for is @RequestBody.
Meaning you would be looking for something similar to :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myUrl",method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String saveData( @RequestBody Map<String,Object> body) {
```

Comment: I am getting `null` in back end,  do i need to change to modify my java file also ?

Comment: getting `Method Not Allowed` after updating java, also i don't have pojo for this request, this is simple key value pair

Comment: Your "POJO" is the Map<string,object> im asuming your `myUrl` variable is set to the right url. You can add this `consumes = { "application/json" }` to your RequestMapping annotation to be more specific

Comment: yes, it is correct url. it's corporate url. hence I didn't disclosed here. getting same error  `Method Not Allowed` . m also trying other approaches.

Comment: basic @RequestBody with a java.util. Map should work. Method not allowed can be because of a number of things. one being having something as required which isn't

Comment: No use, tried commenting  either `contentType` , `dataType` and also both. My data looks like `[["CIQ_2","aa"],["CIQ_3","78965412300"],["CIQ_4","aaa@aa.aaa"],[1,"1"]...]` . might help to understand issue

Answer (score 1):

This should work

page

```html
<button id="doPost"> post </button>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var map = new Map();
            map.set('CIQ_2','aa');
            map.set('CIQ_3','78965412300');

            console.log(map);

            $("#doPost").click (function() {
                var settings = {
                    beforeSend: function(xhr, options) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type" ,"application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:  '/post' ,
                    data: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(map))
                }

                $.ajax(settings).done(function(result) {
                    console.log("done : " + result);
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Controller

```
    @PostMapping("/post")
    @ResponseBody
    public String post(@RequestBody Map<String,String> data) {
        System.out.println(data);
        return "data well received";
    }
```

will print
`{CIQ_2=aa, CIQ_3=78965412300}`

working code on [GitHub](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/post-ajax-map-to-controller/tree/master)